# Why four roots to this equation: $(7x+1)^{1 \over 3}+(8+x-x^2)^{1 \over 3}+(x^2-8x-1)^{1 \over 3}=2$

Tags: roots

> $$(7x+1)^{1 \over 3}+(8+x-x^2)^{1 \over 3}+(x^2-8x-1)^{1 \over 3}=2$$

I figured the roots are $0$, $1$, $-1$, and $9$. But why?

Comment: How did you find those four roots?

Comment: Lots of guesswork.

Comment: Oh ok. So is it fair to say that you're not yet convinced that these are all of the roots?

Comment: If you calculate the derivative of it then it's easy to see that'll be positive for any $|x| > N$ for some relatively small N (probably 10 even) and so only a relatively small intervall needs investigation.

Comment: why how many roots you wanted this to have?

Comment: @chx  Why do you think $x = 0$ is a root?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yes zero is a root

Comment: Are you asking why $4$ roots exist? Or why the roots are the values you calculated?

Comment: Why on earth are you closing an upvoted question with three upvoted answers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why does this equation has $4$ roots? The short answer is it is an accident.
For similar problem like
$$(7x-6)^{1/3}+(8+x-x^2)^{1/3}+(x^2-8x-1)^{1/3}=1
$$
You can get $5$ instead of $4$ solutions.

Define $a,b,c$ like Blue's answer.
$$\begin{cases}
a^3 &= 7x + 1 \\
b^3 &= 8 + x - x^2 \\
c^3 &= x^2 - 8 x - 1
\end{cases}
$$
The key of the whole thing is $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 8$ which is independent of $x$
and $8 = 2^3$.

If $a + b + c = 2$, we will have
$$0 = (a+b+c)^3 - (a^3+b^3+c^3) = 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) = 3(2-c)(2-a)(2-b)$$
This implies one of $a, b, c$ is equal to $2$ and hence one of $a^3, b^3, c^3$ is $8$.

- $a^3 = 8 \implies x = 1$,
- $b^3 = 8 \implies x - x^2 = 0 \iff x(x-1) = 0 \implies x = 0 \text{ or } 1$.
- $c^3 = 8 \implies x^2 - 8x = 9  \iff (x-9)(x+1) = 0 \implies x = -1\text{ or } 9$.

As you can see, the first case is a linear equation, it give you one possible solution.
The remaining two cases are quadratic equation, each of them given you two possible solutions. This means in principle, you can have $5$ possible solutions.
However, one of the solution $x = 1$ has been duplicated, so you are left with $4$ distinct possible solutions.

It remains to check the above 4 possible choice of $x$ are indeed solutions of the
original problem. Instead of plugging in the values of $x$ to check it is a solution, let me 
use $x = 0$ as an example to illustrate the general pattern. In that case $b^3 = 8$ and we have
$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 8 \implies a^3 + c^3 = (a+c)(a^2 - ac + c^2) = 0$$
Notice $a, c$ are real numbers, this means
$a^2 - ac + c^2 = (a-\frac{c}{2})^2 + \frac34 c^2 \ne 0$ whenever $(a,c) \ne 0$. 
This implies $ a+c = 0$ and hence
$$(a + b + c)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 8 \implies a + b + c = 2$$
As a result, $x = 0$ is indeed a solution. By a similar argument, the other $3$ choices of $x$ are also solutions of the problem.

Comment: +1. I was just about to post something similar, since a now-deleted post by @SiXUlm made me realize that the convenient factorization of $(a+b+c)^3-(a^3+b^3+c^3)$ that I had [just used in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1759189/409) hours ago was relevant here. :)

Comment: This is best because the relatively little background knowledge necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Consider this system of polynomial equations:
$$\begin{align}
a+b+c &= 2 \\
a^3 &= 7x + 1 \\
b^3 &= 8 + x - x^2 \\
c^3 &= x^2 - 8 x - 1
\end{align}$$
Using the [method of resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) (via the oh-so-convenient `Resultant[]` function in Mathematica), we can eliminate $a$, $b$, $c$ to get
$$x^3\;(x-1)^6\;(x+1)^3\;(x - 9 )^3 \;=\; 0$$

Therefore, the only candidate values for $x$ are, as you have previously determined, $0$, $1$, $-1$, and $9$. Sometimes the method of resultants introduces extraneous factors, so we should double-check. As it turns out (assuming the $1/3$ power indicates the *real* cube root of a real number), each of the four candidates is in fact a valid solution. $\square$

Comment: More precisely, you have to take $(-t)^{1/3} = -t^{1/3}$ when $t > 0$, which is **not** the principal branch of the cube root.  For each of the four values of $x$, one of the three cube roots will be of this type.  If you use the principal branch of the cube root, there are no solutions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Ah, of course you're right. I tend to think of the real root as the principal one, whereas the principal root is conventionally defined as the complex number whose argument is (in this case) one-third the argument of the original value. I'll edit.

Answer (score 4):

Let: $(7x+1)^{1/3} = a,(x^2-8x-1)^{1/3} = b, (8+x-x^2)^{1/3} = c.$

You have: $$\begin{cases} a+b+c = 2 \\ a^3+b^3+c^3 = 8 \end{cases} \Rightarrow a^3+b^3+c^3 = (a+b+c)^3$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow a^3+b^3 = (a+b+c)^3-c^3 = (a+b)[(a+b+c)^2+c(a+b+c)+c^2)]$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow a+b = 0 \text{ or }a^2-ab+b^2 = (a+b+c)^2+c(a+b+c)+c^2 $$

The first case is easy: $a = -b \Leftrightarrow a^3 = -b^3 \Leftrightarrow 7x+1 = x^2-8x-1 \Leftrightarrow ... $

The second case is equivalent to:
$$ab+c(a+b)+c^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow (a+c)(b+c) = 0$$
I guess you can finish the rest.