# Solve the system of equations: $a+b+c=2$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=6$, $a^3+b^3+c^3=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If we have \begin{cases} a+b+c=2 \\ a^2+b^2+c^2=6 \\ a^3+b^3+c^3=8\end{cases} then what is the value of $a,b,c$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 9):

Note this convenient fact: $$(a+b+c)^3-(a^3+b^3+c^3) = 3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$
Since we know the left-hand side is zero, we also know the right-hand side is zero; this tells us that at least one of these is true:
$$a+b=0 \qquad b+c=0 \qquad c+a=0 \tag{$\star$}$$
We'll go ahead and take the middle one (the others will work out similarly), so that $c = -b$. Then, we have
$$2 = a + b + c = a + 0 = a$$
which gives us $a$. Also
$$6 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2^2 + b^2 + (-b)^2 = 4 + 2 b^2$$
which gives us $b^2 = 1$, so that $b$ is either $+1$ or $-1$, and $c$ is its opposite.

If we'd made a different choice at $(\star)$, we'd have gotten the same values, $2$, $1$, $-1$, assigned to different variables. That's to be expected, since the original equations are *symmetric* in $a$, $b$, $c$; the letters are interchangeable. Therefore, the best we can say here is that

> $$\{ a, b, c\} = \{2, 1, -1\}$$

Comment: This is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here I am giving Solution of yours first question, Next time when you post question,

plz show your try.

Let $x=a,x=b\;,x=c$ be the roots of the equation $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) =0$

So $$x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc=0.............(1)$$

Now here $a+b+c=2$ and $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)$

So we get $ab+bc+ca = -1$ and $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\left[a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca\right]$$

So we get $8-3abc=2[6+1]\Rightarrow abc=-2$

Put all value in equation $(1)\;,$ We get $x^3-2x^2-x+2=0$

So we get $$x^3-2x^2-x+2=(x+1)(x-1)(x-2) =0$$

So we get $x=1\;,-1\;,2$

So we get $$a,b,c\in \left\{-1,1,2\right\}$$, bcz Given equation are symmetrical in $a,b,c$

Answer (score 3):

Since the expressions you know the value of are homogeneous and symmetric in $a,b,c$, we know (or should know) they are expressible in terms of *homogeneous polynomials in the elementary symmetric functions* $E_1=a+b+c$, $E_2=ab+ac+bc$, $E_3=abc$ and in polynomial terms.

In order to find these expressions I prefer a more systematic approach, which can be as follows, rather than plugging in the values and going by attempts.

Degree considerations tell us that
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2=\alpha E_1^2+\beta E_2
$$
With $(a,b,c)=(1,0,0)$ we obtain $1=\alpha$; with $(a,b,c)=(1,1,0)$ we get $2=4\alpha+\beta$. Thus $\beta=-2$.

Also
$$
a^3+b^3+c^3=\alpha E_1^3+\beta E_1E_2+\gamma E_3
$$
With $(a,b,c)=(1,0,0)$ we obtain $1=\alpha$; with $(a,b,c)=(1,1,0)$ we get $2=8\alpha+2\beta=0$; with $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$ we get $3=27\alpha+9\beta+\gamma$. Therefore $\beta=-3$ and $\gamma=3$.

The relations are then
$$
\begin{cases}
a^2+b^2+c^2=E_1^2-2E_2\\[4px]
a^3+b^3+c^3=E_1^3-3E_1E_2+3E_3
\end{cases}
$$
Since you're given $E_1=2$, $a^2+b^2+c^2=6$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=8$, the relations become
$$
E_2=-1,\qquad
E_3=2E_2=-2
$$
Why is this important? Because given $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$, the polynomial having $a,b,c$ as roots is
$$
x^3-E_1x^2+E_2x-E_3
$$
(Viète's formulas). Thus the polynomial is
$$
x^3-2x^2-x+2=x^2(x-2)-(x-2)=(x^2-1)(x-2)=(x-1)(x+2)(x-2)
$$
and you found the roots.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)=a^3+b^3+c^3+ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(a+c)$$
$$(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)=a^3+b^3+c^3+ab(2-c)+bc(2-a)+ca(2-b)$$
$$12=8+2(ab+bc+ca)-3abc$$

Now,
$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)$$
$$2(ab+bc+ca)=4-6=-2$$

Thus,

$$12=8-2-3abc$$

$$abc=-2$$

Let
$$f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc$$
$$f(x)=x^3-2x^2-x+2$$

The values of $a,b,c$ are the roots of $f(x)$.

By trial and error, clearly $1$ is a root.

Then, $$x^3-2x^2-x+2=(x-1)(x^2-x-2)=(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)$$

The values of $a,b,c$ are thus $-1,1,2$ in any order.

Comment: But now that it is correct, why not factorise it!

Comment: @almagest Done.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to determine this---which is by no means perfect, and will not work all of the time!---is to try a few small integers. The best one to focus on is the second equation:
$$
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 6
$$
since all of the terms must be positive. Note that if $a = \pm3$, say, then $a^2 = 9$, which means that all terms have to be from the set $\{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\}$. They can't all be $\pm1$, since that would be to small, so at least one has to be $\pm2$.

Can you see where to go from here? You can also simplify by noting that the solution is symmetric under swapping $a \to b \to c$ (or any other permutation), so you can assume for simplicity that $a$ is the largest in absolute value.

Comment: Is it mentioned any where that $a,b,c$ are strictly integers????

Comment: No, but given that there is an integer solution, this is one way to find it. It depends on the level of the question, I suppose.

Comment: The assumption is not valid in this case since there is no condition on what $a,b,c$ are. SO you should accordingly edit your answer and change the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Newton's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) for recovering the values of $ab+ac+bc$ and $abc$, in order to compute $a,b,c$ from the factorization of $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$. As an alternative, we may understand which conditions on $P_1,P_2,P_3$ grant that if $a+b=P_1$ and $a^2+b^2=P_2$, then $a^3+b^3=P_3$. We have:
$$ P_1 P_2 = P_3 + ab(a+b) = P_3+P_1\cdot\frac{P_1^2-P_2}{2} $$
or:
$$ 2 P_3 = 3 P_1 P_2 - P_1^3.$$
Assuming $c=1$, we have $(P_1,P_2,P_3)=(1,5,7)$ that fulfills the previous condition, hence we may assume $a+b=1$ and $a^2+b^2=5$. The solutions are so given by the permutations of $\color{red}{(-1,1,2)}$.